# How can I pass a QueryString parameter to Flash swf through html <object> movie parameter?

Tags: xml, flash, query-string

I have a html  for render Flash swf files and this has its parameter "movie" and this "movie" value is the url of the swf.

And in my swf, I have a method loadXml("myXMLFile.xml") that reads a xml, get its attributes and show them in swf. So far so good...

But, what I'm looking for is to pass a QueryString in the movie value, such as "myMovie.swf?myFile=anotherXMLFile.xml" and makes the swf loads this querystring parameter and loads the "anotherXMLFile.xml" instead of the "myXMLFile.xml".

**That is... I want to dynamically send to swf the XML File I want to load...**

Is there a way to do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out this post:

[Flash: Passing Variables to Flash from HTML via Query String](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashQueryString/)

If that doesn't take care of what you're looking for, you can also check out:

[SwfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

SwfObject gives you a way to load up a SWF and pass parameters to the SWF via javascript. You could access your page query string variables and pass them to the SWF that way.

Comment: Justin, I used swfobject and aldo chekcked the link you passed me... hehehe But, My doubt is to get this parameter in Flash... I this the example in the link very complicated and should be an easier way to accomplish this.

Comment: This is helpful but the basic solution as far as retrieving that variable in Flash using AS3, for me, has been to pull it in as a `string` like so: `var myFileVar:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.myFile as String` and then use it from there. I'm not sure if `as String` is necessary, but it's safer than not. I'm definitely not an AS3 expert, but this was what I found when searching around and I thought I'd leave my solution here.